# How to prove that such a coloring of the subsets exists?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

Let $S$ be a set with 2002 elements, and let $N$ be an integer with $0 \le N \le 2^{2002}$. Prove that it is possible to color every subset of $S$ either blue or red so that the following conditions hold:

(a) the union of any two red subsets is red;

(b) the union of any two blue subsets is blue;

(c) there are exactly $N$ red subsets.

What does the phrase coloring of subsets mean? I also found a link which provides the solution

https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=2002_USAMO_Problems/Problem_1

In this solution why do we consider the case where $N \geq 2^k$. N equal to $2^k$ is fine, but isn't N an integer less than $2^k$ since in the solution we proceed by induction to generalise it for any integer n, not only 2002?

Comment: Once again, you are just cutting and pasting problems with absolutely no effort shown.  This one comes from the $2002$ usamo.  As with your other problems, the solution to this one can easily be found online. [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=2002_USAMO_Problems/Problem_1) is the solution to this one.

Comment: @lulu I haven't checked, but I would be flabbergasted if that last paragraph made its way into the problem's original statement. :-)

Comment: The "coloring of the subsets" refers to a function from the power set of $S$ to a two element set $\lbrace \text{red}, \text{blue}\rbrace$. Basically, you can define a rule that takes any subset of $S$ and assigns it one of two values.

Comment: @TheoBendit Thanks for the help

Comment: @lulu You are right, I did do that, I even found the solution but didn't really understand it. Do you think I add this solution and also show the step I didn't add, perhaps that would satisfy and maintain the reputation of this website?

Comment: If there is a step which confuses you, ask about that step specifically.    Though the link I provided gives two quite different solutions.

Comment: @lulu let me include the link to the solution as well as the step with which I have a problem

Comment: In that first solution, the author claims to prove a stronger statement then the problem requires.  That is, the solution is meant to work for all finite sets, not just those with $2002$ elements.  The proof is inductive, on $k$.  The author assumes (inductively) that the proof is known for sets of order $k$ and is now trying to prove it for sets of order $k+1$.  Thus, $N$ might be as large as $2^{k+1}$.

Comment: @lulu How can I show that after coloring all subsets which contain s blue, I can properly color S'?

Comment: That's just the inductive hypothesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the inductive step we assume we have proven that for any set of size $k$ we can properly color the subsets so that $N$ of them are red for any $N$ in the range $[0,2^k]$.  We now want to prove the same for $k+1$, which means there are $2^{k+1}$ subsets and we need to show that we can properly color them for any $N$ in the range $[0,2^{k+1}]$.  We divide the set into $\{s\}$, the new element and $S'$, which is everything else and has $k$ elements.

The proof then says essentially, if $N \le 2^k$ we had a proper coloring of $S'$ with $N$ subsets colored red, so color all the subsets that include $s$ blue and we are done.  If $N \gt 2^k$ you can take all the subsets that include $s$, which is $2^k$ of them, color them red, and fill out with a proper coloring of the set with $k$ elements that has $N-2^k$ red subsets.